# Is there a default type for numbers in Java

Tags: java, types, numbers, integer, default

If I write something like this

```
System.out.println(18);
```

Which type has the '18'?
Is it *int* or *byte*?
Or doesn't it have a type yet?

It can't be int, because something like this is correct:

```
byte b = 3;
```

And this is incorrect:

```
int i = 3;
byte bb = i; //error!
```

EDIT:
I think I found the right part in the spec at [Assignment Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) :

> The compile-time narrowing of constants means that code such as:
>
> byte theAnswer = 42;
>
> is allowed. Without the narrowing, the fact that the integer literal 42 has type int would mean that a cast to byte would be required:
>
> byte theAnswer = (byte) 42;  // cast is permitted but not required

Comment: Pretty sure it is an int

Comment: Primitive conversion is carefully spelled out in the Java specs. An integral type will default to `int` but there are specific rules for narrowing and widening conversions. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This

```
18
```

is known as an [integer literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1). There are all sorts of [literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10), floating point, `String`, character, etc.

In the following,

```
byte b = 3;
```

the literal `3` is an integer literal. It's also a constant expression. And since Java can tell that `3` fits in a `byte`, it can safely apply a [narrowing primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) and store the result in a `byte` variable.

In this

```
int i = 3;
byte bb = i; //error!
```

the literal `3` is a constant expression, but the variable `i` is not. The compiler simply decides that `i` is not a constant expression and therefore doesn't go out of its way to figure out its value, a conversion to `byte` may lose information (how to convert `12345` to a `byte`?) and should therefore not be allowed. You can override this behavior by making `i` a constant variable

```
final int i = 3;
byte bb = i; // no error!
```

or by specifying an explicit cast

```
int i = 3;
byte bb = (byte) i; // no error!
```

Answer (score 3):

The [JLS-4.2.1 - Integral Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> - For `byte`, from -128 to 127, inclusive
> - For `short`, from -32768 to 32767, inclusive
> - For `int`, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive
> - For `long`, from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive
> - For `char`, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535

And [JLS-3.10.1 - Integer Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

Finally, [JLS-3.10.2 - Floating-Point Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) includes

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d (§4.2.3).

As for `byte b = 3;` it is a [Narrowing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) from `int` to `byte`.

Comment: So the compiler is smart enough when you type any number in java (integral value) to set it to the correct byte, short, int, or long data type (performing either narrowing or widening from an INT) huh? interesting

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, it's an integer literal.

Under the hood, it appears Java was written for 32 bit processors.
An integer is between +/- ~2.147 million, which is 2^31 with a signage bit.

So whether you're writing a bit or a full int, it's a single processor function, therefore a single memory allocation.